# Converting from Map<String, String> to POJO

Tags: java, csv, deserialization, objectmapper

I'm creating a CSV loader class which reads records from CSV files and returns a `List<T>` where T is the target POJO class.

Sample CSV:
[image: test.csv]

From the extracted records from CSV, it is possible to get `0` value for a `Date` field of a POJO class. From the sample CSV, record #2 where the value of `createdDate` is `0`. How do I change `0` to a valid date (e.g `1970-01-01 09:00:00`) first before the actual deserialization happens?

I have successfully created the process of reading a CSV file to conversion to returning `List<T>`.

1. Parsing: `org.apache.commons.csv`
2. Conversion: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`
   I am thinking of overriding some functions of my `ObjectMapper` to manipulate the values, but I have no idea how to do it.

```java
private List<T> convertToObjectList(List<Map<String, String>> csvRecordMapList, Class<T> targetClass) {
  List<T> csvRecordObjList = new ArrayList<>();
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  objectMapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);        
  objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
  for(Map<String, String> recordMap : csvRecordMapList)
    csvRecordObjList.add(objectMapper.convertValue(recordMap, targetClass));

  return csvRecordObjList;
}
```

If I have `0` for a `Date` field for the target POJO class, I get the error message below (which is already expected):

```
Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '0': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '0': Unparseable date: "0")
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have to read the CSV into a list of maps first? Why not read the CSV line by line and do your conversion to class T directly?

Comment: Yes, I need the list of maps for further processing, so I thought I should do it this way to minimize redundancy. The class loader must be generic to accommodate different class T, that's why I want to use existing libraries for the POJO conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using ObjectMapper, I used org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils and ConvertUtils. I found out that you can add a customized converter. Below are my updated source codes:

```
private List<T> convertToObjectList(List<Map<String, String>> csvRecordMapList, Class<T> targetClass)
    throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
    List<T> csvRecordObjList = new ArrayList<>();
    ConvertUtils.register(getDateConverter(), Date.class);
    for (Map<String, String> recordMap : csvRecordMapList) {
        T targetClassObj = targetClass.newInstance();
        BeanUtils.populate(targetClassObj, recordMap);
        csvRecordObjList.add(targetClassObj);
    }

    return csvRecordObjList;
}
```

And this is my customized converter:

```
private static Converter getDateConverter() {
    return new Converter() {
        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
        @Override
        public Object convert(Class classType, Object value) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = value.equals("0") ? new Date(0) : sdf.parse((String) value);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // Do nothing
            }
            return date;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this below. (code is not compiled).

```
for(Map<String, String> recordMap : csvRecordMapList) {
    if(recordMap.getKey().equals("createdDate") && recordMap.value().equals("0")) {
        recordMap.put("createdDate", "1970-01-01 09:00:00");
    } 
    csvRecordObjList.add(objectMapper.convertValue(recordMap, targetClass));
}
```

Comment: The class loader must be generic to accommodate different class T, that means "createdDate" is not consistent to different classes. That would have been the go to solution. But, thank you for the idea! :)